Compute Tor-functor $\mathrm{Tor}^R_r(R/\mathfrak{m}_i,R/\mathfrak{m}_j)$ for $R=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$?

[Q] Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$. Let $\mathfrak{m}_0=(x,y)$ and $\mathfrak{m}_1=(x-1,y-1)$. Compute $$\mathrm{Tor}^R_r(R/\mathfrak{m}_i,R/\mathfrak{m}_j)$$ for $i,j\in\{0,1\}$?

It seems not easy to find a projective resolution, it there some easy method to solve this?
Note that we can consider $0\to\mathfrak{m}_i\to R\to R/\mathfrak{m}_i\to0$. Then we can induce the long exact sequence which shows that $\mathrm{Tor}^R_r(R/\mathfrak{m}_i,R/\mathfrak{m}_j)=\mathrm{Tor}^R_{r-1}(\mathfrak{m}_i,R/\mathfrak{m}_j)=\mathrm{Tor}^R_{r-2}(\mathfrak{m}_i,\mathfrak{m}_j)$ for $r\geq 3$ and $\mathrm{Tor}^R_1(R/\mathfrak{m}_i,R/\mathfrak{m}_j)=\mathfrak{m}_i\cap\mathfrak{m}_j/\mathfrak{m}_i\mathfrak{m}_j$
and $\mathrm{Tor}^R_2(R/\mathfrak{m}_i,R/\mathfrak{m}_j)=\ker(\mathfrak{m}_i\otimes_R\mathfrak{m}_j\to\mathfrak{m}_i\mathfrak{m}_j)$.
How about next???
Thank you very much!

Now I have a solution as below.

A friend taught me a method to solve this problem.
First we consider $\mathrm{Tor}^R_r(R/\mathfrak{m}_0,R/\mathfrak{m}_i)$ and we just need to find a projective resolution of $R/\mathfrak{m}_0$.
Note that $R=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)\cong k[t^2,t^3]$ via $x\mapsto t^3$ and $y\mapsto t^2$. Now $\mathfrak{m}_0=(t^2,t^3)$. Consider $R^2\to R$ given by $(t^2,t^3)$ and we want to find its kernel. Let $f=\sum_{i=0}a_it^i$ and $g=\sum_{i=0}b_it^i$ (now $a_1=b_1=0$ since we are in $R=k[t^2,t^3]$) such that $t^2f+t^3g=0$ which implies $a_0=b_0=a_2=0$ and $a_i=b_{i-1}$ for $i\geq 3$. This force we have the exact sequence
$$0\to\mathfrak{m}_0\stackrel{(t,-id)}{\to}R^2\stackrel{(t^2,t^3)}{\to}R\to R/\mathfrak{m}_0\to0$$
This will give us a cyclic resolution as follows:
$$\cdots\to R^2\stackrel{\begin{pmatrix}t^3&t^4\\-t^2&-t^3\end{pmatrix}}{\to}R^2\stackrel{\begin{pmatrix}t^3&t^4\\-t^2&-t^3\end{pmatrix}}{\to}R^2\stackrel{(t^2,t^3)}{\to}R\to R/\mathfrak{m}_0\to0.$$
As $t^2,t^3$ is zero in $R/\mathfrak{m}_0$ we get
$$R/\mathfrak{m}_0\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_{R}R/\mathfrak{m}_0
\cong k[0]\oplus\bigoplus_{n\geq1}k^2[n].$$
Similar as $R/\mathfrak{m}_0\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_{R}R/\mathfrak{m}_1$ which is zero.
Now consider $\mathrm{Tor}^R_r(R/\mathfrak{m}_1,R/\mathfrak{m}_1)$.
This is also a $k$-vector spaces and we just need to find the rank. So we just need to consider
$$\mathrm{Tor}^R_r(R/\mathfrak{m}_1,R/\mathfrak{m}_1)_{\mathfrak{m}_1}
\cong\mathrm{Tor}^{R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}}_r(R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}/\mathfrak{m}_1R_{\mathfrak{m}_1},R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}/\mathfrak{m}_1R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}).$$
Now $\mathfrak{m}_1$ is a smooth point and easy to see that $x-y$, which is also a regular sequence, generated $\mathfrak{m}_1R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}$ by easy computation (as we need to find a line meet this curve transversely). Hence by Koszul resolution we get
$$R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}/\mathfrak{m}_1R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_{R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}}  R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}/\mathfrak{m}_1R_{\mathfrak{m}_1}
\cong k[0]\oplus k[1].$$
Well done!
